# For any measure right?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ A , B \subset \mathbb{R}$. Does  $m^* (A \cup B) + m^* (A \cap B) \le m^* (A) +m^* (B)$ hold  for every measure? Example, for outer measure, Lebesgue measure, etc.

Comment: Outer measure is not actually a measure...

Comment: @nim You should know!

Comment: @nim: An outer measure $m^*$ is defined on all subsets of the space and satisfies (1) and (2) in my answer below and also that $m^*(\varnothing)=0$. A measure $m$ is defined only on the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra, and satisfies (i) $m(\varnothing)=0$ and (ii) $m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} E_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}m(E_j)$ whenever the $\{E_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ are disjoint.

Comment: I "do actually know the answer" but I do not actually understand whether you actually know the definition of outer measures and of measures. Apparently not, but how come you don't, if you are interested in this question? (Note: my first comment is a reaction to a now deleted comment by the OP asking why outer measures are not (always) measures.)

Comment: I deleted my first comment, Did.I am not proficient in this topic.

Comment: @nim Be careful: The Lebesgue measure is _not_ an outer measure, because it is not defined for all sets. There exist sets that are not Lebesgue measurable (for example, the Vitali sets).

Comment: @triple_sec you are actually proficient in this topic. thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>It is true.</s> Let $m^*$ be an outer measure. (As pointed out by @Potato, an outer measure may not be a measure. However, (1) and (2) below can be shown to remain true for measures, too, when the domain is restricted to the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra.) By definition,

(1) $m^*(E)\leq m^*(F)$ if $E\subseteq F$; and

(2) $m^*(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}m^*(E_j)$. (This is obviously true for finite unions and sums, too, as we can take $E_j=\varnothing$ for $j$ sufficiently large and greater, and we also know that $m^*(\varnothing)=0$ by the definition of outer measures or actual measures.)

---

**Edited on April 30, 2016. As Vim pointed out, the inequalities (3) and (4) below are invalid in general.** Parts of the text I have correspondingly retracted are struck out throughout my answer. (3) and (4) actually hold as equalities if $m^*$ is a measure and $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets, but they do not necessarily hold if $m^*$ is a generic outer measure and the sets $A$ and $B$ are not measurable. I do not have an immediate idea on how to fix this proof or construct a counterexample for general outer measures, so further input is welcome.

---

<s>Now, note that</s>

(3) $m^*(A)=m^*\left((A\setminus B)\bigcup(A\bigcap B)\right)\geq m^*(A\setminus B)+m^*(A\bigcap B)$ by (2), and similarly:

(4) $m^*(B)=m^*\left((B\setminus A)\bigcup(A\bigcap B)\right)\geq m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A\bigcap B)$.

But note also that $(A\setminus B)\bigcup(B\setminus A)\bigcup(A\bigcap B)=A\bigcup B$. Therefore, (2) implies that

(5) $m^*(A\setminus B)+m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A\bigcap B)\geq m^*\left((A\setminus B)\bigcup(B\setminus A)\bigcup(A\bigcap B)\right)=m^*(A\bigcup B)$.

Finally, combining (3)-(5) yields

$m^*(A)+m^*(B)\geq m^*(A\setminus B)+m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A\bigcap B)+m^*(A\bigcap B)\geq m^*(A\bigcup B)+m^*(A\bigcap B),$

which is the desired result. This is true for both measures and outer measures, since, as pointed out above, (1) and (2) hold for both measures and outer measures.

Comment: tanks very much triple_sec.

Comment: @nim You're welcome.

Comment: I don't get your 3),4). For example, I think $$m^*(A)\ge m^*(A-B)+m^*(A\cap B)$$ is true in general by subadditivity, but not the other way round..

Comment: @Vim You’re right (with $\leq$ instead of $\geq$ in your inequality). As I submitted this answer more than two and a half years ago, I can’t remember what I had in mind, but I apparently made an embarrassing mistake. If you have an idea on how to salvage the proof or construct a counterexample, please submit an alternative answer. I will notify OP to unaccept my answer.

Comment: @nim As Vim pointed out, some aspects of my answer are flawed—see above for details. I encourage you to unaccept it and open the floor to further answers improving upon mine. I apologize for this mistake.

Comment: @triple_sec the result itself  is right, though. And can indeed be proved via open set approximation.

Comment: @triple_sec the result itself  is right, though. And can indeed be proved via open set approximation.

Comment: @Vim Even if $m^*$ is not necessarily the Lebesgue outer measure, but any arbitrary outer measure on $\mathbb R$? I would love to see the details.

Comment: @triple_sec i think it only holds for Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Vim True. My inequalities go through as they are reported (actually many of them as equalities) if $m^*$ is a measure (not even necessarily the Lebesgue measure) on some $\sigma$-algebra, because then the measure of any finite or countable disjoint union equals the sum of the measures of the constituents. No topological approximations are needed then. The dilemma here that made me retract my answer is whether OP’s conjecture holds for generic _outer_ measures.

Comment: @triple_sec yeah. If it's not Lebesgue outer measure, $\epsilon$-approximation via elementary sets could be difficult. Indeed, my observation to solve this problem is that $$m^*(E)=\inf_{U\,\text{open},\,E\subset U} m^*(U).$$

Comment: @triple_sec it turns out that as long as the outer measure is indeed a measure on Borel sets (satisfies finite additivity at least), and  assumes inner or outer regularity, then the $\epsilon-$ approximation proof still goes through.